# convert output of dsolve to function

Tags: matlab, function, symbolic-math

How do I convert the expression which is solution to a differential equation to a function?

```
syms T(x)
ode = diff(T,x,2) + 0.002*(20 - T) == 0;
dsolve(ode, T(0) == 40, T(10) == 200)
```

The output of `dsolve` is an expression in variable `x`. I need to change it into function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`matlabFunction`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) on the output of `dsolve` to convert from symbolic expression to function handle:

```
syms T(x)
ode = diff(T,x,2) + 0.002*(20 - T) == 0;
s = dsolve(ode, T(0) == 40, T(10) == 200);
f = matlabFunction(s);
```

This produces `f` as a handle to an [anonymous function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).